# Is it possible to iterate backwards over a tensorboard events file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

The [tf.compat.v1.train.summary_iterator](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/train/summary_iterator) method creates a generator object of `Event` protocol buffers suitable for forward iteration. Is there a way to iterate backwards, instead of forwards, over events?

The following code is an example usage of the forward generator:

```
for e in tf.compat.v1.train.summary_iterator(path to events file):
    for v in e.summary.value:
        if v.tag == 'loss':
            print(v.simple_value)
```